# Why isn't the background color in my nav region correct

Tags: css

I am working on a project for a class using an older version of twitter bootstrap, and in the process I discovered something odd with my background-colors.

On both the `<nav>` and one of the `<div>` elements I specify the same background color #D3D3D3, but when I view the page in my browser the two sections have different grays for their backgrounds.

Any ideas why this is and how to fix it would be appreciated.

My page is at:
http://donraikes.github.io/hcj/csstest/

My index.html follows:

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
  <head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">


    <title>Module-3 Solution</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/styles.css">
  </head>
<body style="background-color: white; color: black; font-size: 16">
  <header style="background-color: #D3D3D3;">
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default">
      <div class="container-fluid">
      <div id="nav-header" class="nav-header">
      <h1 class="nav-brand">Food, LLC</h1>

          <button " type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsable-nav" aria-expanded="false">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>

        <div id="collapsable-nav" class="collapse navbar-collapse">
           <ul id="nav-list" class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right hide-md hide-sm visible-xs">
            <li><a href="#">Beef</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Chicken</a></li>
            <li><a href="#">Sushi</a></li>
          </ul><!-- #nav-list -->
          </div>
    </div>
    </div>
    </nav>
  </header>
    <h2 class="text-center">Our Menu</h2>
    <div class="container">
    <div id="mainsection" class="col-xs-12" style="background-color: #D3D3D3">
    <h3 class="text-center">Chicken</h3>
<p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Suspendisse et fermentum ligula. Aenean sollicitudin rhoncus fermentum. Maecenas laoreet, sem non dictum venenatis, mauris ipsum maximus mi, non pulvinar orci nisi a justo. Pellentesque vehicula convallis leo at feugiat. Praesent finibus lorem nibh. Mauris pellentesque sagittis eleifend. Donec rhoncus eros a ex hendrerit tincidunt. Donec quis tempus tellus. Pellentesque vitae ipsum sed sapien consectetur posuere.</p>
<p>Suspendisse dignissim tristique sem vitae viverra. Pellentesque pulvinar mi a lorem lobortis euismod. Maecenas massa nisl, venenatis ullamcorper metus eu, semper dapibus nunc. Praesent vulputate aliquet arcu. Fusce suscipit arcu ut ipsum varius, sed sagittis elit vestibulum. Morbi ac bibendum massa. Curabitur pellentesque auctor ipsum, sed varius turpis pretium sed. Sed augue purus, accumsan id diam sed, ullamcorper lobortis justo. Nulla facilisi. Praesent lacinia iaculis pellentesque. Nulla sed finibus nibh, at vulputate purus. Aliquam erat volutpat. In ac est a nisi volutpat mattis vitae sed est.</p>
<p>Duis ullamcorper nulla sit amet tortor condimentum, at molestie massa hendrerit. Nulla quis scelerisque lectus. Vivamus placerat, erat eget tincidunt bibendum, felis metus tincidunt mauris, ac consequat odio arcu ut diam. Etiam sit amet aliquet augue, eget vestibulum magna. Donec at facilisis elit. Morbi eu massa iaculis, aliquet massa sit amet, sollicitudin mi. Integer commodo metus eu massa tempor, vitae sodales enim fermentum. Nam lobortis dui vel odio imperdiet bibendum. Vestibulum aliquam purus orci, vitae pharetra felis pulvinar sit amet. Morbi sodales arcu ligula, maximus rutrum risus ultricies vitae. Ut velit nibh, feugiat eleifend ultricies quis, volutpat in arcu. Fusce dapibus erat risus, nec volutpat nisl pellentesque non. Nam nisi sem, dictum at neque sit amet, fermentum dictum mi. Phasellus rutrum, enim at vehicula hendrerit, ex magna elementum orci, id malesuada nulla leo non dui. Proin vitae interdum dui.</p>
    </div>
    </div>


  <!-- jQuery (Bootstrap JS plugins depend on it) -->
  <script src="js/jquery-1.11.3.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  <script src="js/script.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1):

You have applied `background-color: #D3D3D3;` to the `header` that is parent to `nav.navbar-default`. However, `nav.navbar-default` has a `background-color` specification from line 395 of navbar.less that is displaying over the `header`.

For `background-color: #D3D3D3;` to be visible, apply it inline to `nav.navbar-default`.

```html
<body style="background-color: white; color: black; font-size: 16">
  <header>
    <nav id="header-nav" class="navbar navbar-default" style="background-color: #D3D3D3;">
      ...
```